# Catering our daughter's wedding

Tags: catering

My husband and I will be catering our daughters wedding. It's a very simple ceremony with about 120 to 130 people. An afternoon wedding with the reception right after. My question is how do you figure how much meat per person. We will be having chicken (fried), ham and turkey. Potato salad, green salad, and a fruit salad. Would love any input anyone can give me!!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

1/2 pound to 1 pound per person is standard for US when planning meat amount; pending on the overall average guess and type of party.

For sides; figure on 2-3 gallons = 50 people

Another way to look at it; since you have so many sides.
1-1.5 pounds of food per person; total.

Answer (score 0):

that is very simple: in europe we do 120 grams of meat per person (not including bone) and in the US I think it is 200 grams, festive occasion, 300 grams max per person.

Comment: In the US we don't measure anything in grams...

Comment: You are welcome to convert it to whatever scale you like to use